# Could "Win32_Processor ProcessorID" attribute change value with no hardware modifications

Tags: windows-xp, wmi, windows-xp-sp3

I have been using WMI to get information about hardware. Some informations appears to DO NOT change. One of these is "Win32_Processsor ProcessorID".

Anyway, I have a machine (with just one phisical processor) where the query returns different values occasionally.

Do you know something about it?

BTW, running WMI queries on an Windows XP SP3.